# How to show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n^2-1)^{1/n}=1$ rigorously

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

According to the definition of convergence

> $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\, \mid(n^2-1)^{1/n}-1\mid<\epsilon, \forall n>N $.

I am trying to find the relevant $N\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfies above condition, here is so far where I get stucked.

$$\mid(n^2-1)^{1/n}-1\mid<\epsilon$$
$$(n^2-1)^{1/n}<\epsilon+1$$
$$(n^2-1)<(\epsilon+1)^n$$
$$\ln(n+1)+\ln(n-1)<n\ln(\epsilon+1)$$

I don't know how to put all of $n$'s onto onside and then pick the size of $N$

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652216/42969 for an answer to a very similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

Let us consider
\begin{align}
x_n = (n^2-1)^{1/n}-1 \geq 0
\end{align}
when $n\geq 2$. Then it follows
\begin{align}
n^2-1=(1+x_n)^n \geq \binom{n}{3}x_n^3 = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} x_n^3 \geq 0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
x_n^3 \leq \frac{6(n^2-1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)} = \frac{6(n+1)}{n(n-2)} \leq \frac{12}{(n-2)}.
\end{align}
The rest should be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\varepsilon>0$, take an integer $k$ such that $0<\frac1k<\varepsilon$.

Then for $n\geq3$,
$$
(1+\frac1k)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj\frac1{k^j}\geq1+\frac nk+\frac{n(n-1)}{2k^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6k^3}=\frac{p_k(n)}{6k^3},
$$
where $p_k(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $3$ with coefficient in $\mathbb Z$ and the coefficient of $n^3$ is $1$.

Hence $q_k(n):=p_k(n)-6k^3(n^2-1)$ is also a monic polynomial of degree $3$ with integer coefficients, where **monic** means the coefficient of $n^3$ is $1$.

Now let $N:=4\cdot\max\left\{\text{absolute value of coefficients of } q_k(n)\right\}$. If $N\leq3$, then take $N=3$.

For $n>N$, $q_k(n)\geq n^3-4Nn^2>0$, which means, for $n>N$, we have
$$
n^2-1<\frac{p_k(n)}{6k^3}<(1+\frac1k)^n<(1+\varepsilon)^n.
$$

---

Hope this helps.